# Must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have some pretty basic code, trying to load a UICollectionView with some cells. I keep getting this error, although i don't use storyboards in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can register class or nib this way:

```
   [collectionView registerNib:<#(UINib *)#> forCellWithReuseIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#>];
   [collectionView registerClass:<#(__unsafe_unretained Class)#> forCellWithReuseIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#>];
```

Make sure you use the same reuseIdentifier in code above and here

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

It should be the same not nil string. The best way is to declare it somewhere. For example this way

```
static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"CellReuseIdentifier";
```

Comment: Yes, i am already doing this but still getting the error. It's driving me insane.

Comment: Have you checked reuseIdentifier? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, i've managed to solve the issue. It was something extremely stupid, i won't even tell you what it is, but thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Important:** You must register a class or nib file using the `registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` method before calling this method. You can also register a set of default supplementary views with the layout object using the `registerClass:forDecorationViewOfKind:` or `registerNib:forDecorationViewOfKind:` method.

**[apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerClass%3aforCellWithReuseIdentifier%3a)**

```
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layoutDesign= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    self.yourCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.view addSubView:self.collectionView];  
     [self.yourCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];
     self.yourCollectionView.delegate=self;
     self.yourCollectionView.dataSource=self;
```

Comment: I am doing all of that, registering the nib, the class, adding a layout, adding the delegate, and the data source.